# Prediction with tensorflow-gpu is slower than tensorflow-cpu

Tags: python, tensorflow

Below is my code for prediction:

```
start=time.time()
with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
    predict('/home/4_bikes/test_images/bikerider4.jpg',sess)
    predict('/home/4_bikes/test_images/bikerider4.jpg',sess)
    predict('/home/4_bikes/test_images/bikerider4.jpg',sess)
    predict('/home/4_bikes/test_images/bikerider4.jpg',sess)
    predict('/home/4_bikes/test_images/bikerider4.jpg',sess)
    predict('/home/4_bikes/test_images/bikerider4.jpg',sess)
    predict('/home/4_bikes/test_images/bikerider4.jpg',sess)
    predict('/home/4_bikes/test_images/bikerider4.jpg',sess)
    predict('/home/4_bikes/test_images/bikerider4.jpg',sess)    
stop=time.time()
print('Time taken for prediction :: {}'.format(stop-start))
```

Below is my `predict` function :

```
def predict(file_name,sess):

  t = read_tensor_from_image_file(
      file_name,
      input_height=input_height,
      input_width=input_width,
      input_mean=input_mean,
      input_std=input_std)

  results = sess.run(output_operation.outputs[0], {
        input_operation.outputs[0]: t
    })
  results = np.squeeze(results)

  index=results.argmax()

  prediction=labels[index]
  bike_predictor = bike_classifier()
  if prediction == 'bikes':
    bike_predictor.predict(t)
  else:
    print('Predicted as :: unknown')
```

I have installed tensorflow-gpu on python-2 and tensorflow-cpu on python-3. When I run it with tensorflow-gpu I get:

```
Time taken for prediction :: 2.92091107368
```

When I run with tensorflow-cpu I get:

```
Time taken for prediction :: 1.7942276000976562
```

I am sure I am using GPU because when running with python-2 I get log:

```
name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.6705
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0
totalMemory: 10.91GiB freeMemory: 10.28GiB
2018-05-31 18:23:26.762628: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1435] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2018-05-31 18:23:26.906629: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:923] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2018-05-31 18:23:26.906672: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:929]      0 
2018-05-31 18:23:26.906679: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:942] 0:   N 
2018-05-31 18:23:26.906856: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1053] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 9949 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
```

each time `predict` is called.

Can someone help me with this? Where am I wrong? when using GPU time taken should be less.

For installation I followed [this](https://github.com/markjay4k/Install-Tensorflow-on-Ubuntu-17.10-/blob/master/Tensorflow%20Install%20instructions.ipynb) link.

I am using **Nvidia GeForce GTX 1080 Ti**.

CPU is **Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700K CPU**

Model is **MobileNet_v1**

Comment: The GPU has a CPU part which feeds images. Most likely this is the bottleneck. GPU is sitting ideal most of the time waiting for the images.

Comment: @vijaym anyway to overcome this?

Comment: yes, building a `input data pipeline` using dataset API, where you parallelize data loading part on CPU and the number crunching on GPU.

Comment: Check :https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/performance_guide#general_best_practices

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try to `start=time.time()` put this code after creating session (after`with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:`) for me creating session with gpu takes more time but makes predictions fast. 
Also have you ever tried with well known models I mean is that first time that your gpu gives bad performance?
Maybe try with VGG Nets you can find out benchmarks from [here](https://github.com/jcjohnson/cnn-benchmarks) and compare to your gpu. if something seems to be wrong with your gpu focus on it but maybe that is about your model sometimes models gives much better performances on cpu

Comment: Same result, no change

Comment: @PratikKumar have you ever tried with well known models I mean is that first time that your gpu gives bad performance? Maybe try with VGG Nets you can find out benchmarks from [here](https://github.com/jcjohnson/cnn-benchmarks) and compare to your gpu. if something seems to be wrong with your gpu focus on it but maybe that is about your model sometimes models gives much better performances on cpu.

Comment: I'm running **mobilenet_v1**

Comment: upvote for the idea to test on benchmark architecture. Since, I am using mobilenet which is smaller comapred to other architectures that's why CPU may be faster.

Answer (score 0):

What king of GPU are you using. From what I understood, Tensorflow seems optimized for [cuda](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-download) -> Nvidia

Comment: I use Nvidia  GeForce GTX 1080 Ti.

Comment: That's weird....... What about your OS / drivers? Also, what is your CPU ? (my threadripper 1950X works also better than a GPU in a lot of highly parallelized jobs)

Comment: Driver is **Driver Version: 384.130**. OS is ubuntu-16. CPU is **Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700K CPU @ 4.20GHz**

Comment: So you're using the proprietary software. Check that you have libcuda1-384. If so, I don't have any more clues

Comment: Can you guide me how to check it?